# How to check a radio button in jquery using hot keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button, checked

I have the following radio buttons.

```
<input id="r1" type="radio" name="options" value="1" /> 
<input id="r2" type="radio" name="options" value="2" /> 
<input id="r3" type="radio" name="options" value="3" />
```

For speeding up the form input I want to add hot keys. That is using the "TAB" user can focus on any of the radio button and if he presses my specefied hot keys it will be checked.

For example let user has focused on second radio button and my hot keys are "ctrl" + "space". So when user then press the hot keys only the second radio button will be checked.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 32 && e.ctrlKey) {
           //Focus radio button should be checked
        }
    });
```

How can I do that using jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery Hit key plugin to achieve this instead of writing your own code.

http://github.com/tzuryby/hotkeys

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 32 && e.ctrlKey) {
           e.target.checked = true
        }
    });
```